# How to get value of default database from which the tez query was fired via Aplication Timeline Server

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I want to get the metadata information about all the TEZ jobs that ran on the hadoop cluster. So I referred to the YARN Timeline Server [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServer.html) to get the metadata of jobs done.

I have set the property

> tez.runtime.convert.user-payload.to.history-text

to true.

This property logs additional user information. You can find more details [here](https://tez.apache.org/tez_ui_user_data.html) .

However I am unable to get the default database value. ie the database from which the query was fired.

Example :

These are the set of queries fired using hive with tez engine:

```
Query 1 : use db1;
Query 2 : create table tab1 (id string);
Query 3 : select count(*) from tab1;
```

I need to get the database value "db1" for the job submitted for query 2 via the timeline server api